# How does ssh key works when encrypted with ansible vault? How does ansible.builtin.meta: reset_connection task affects the ssh connection

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys, ansible-inventory, ansible-vault

I am using ansible to perform some tasks on remote virtual machine. In my inventory file I have provided the ssh file as

```
all:
  hosts:
    vm:
      ansible_host: host_ip
      ansible_user: ssh_user_name
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: path to ansible-vault encrypted ssh private key
```

If I use the 'ansible_ssh_private_key_file' in decrypted I don't face any error. But in encrypted form I face "Invalid format error".

```
Load key "path to private ssh key": invalid format
```

I have read couple of similar errors on internet. From where I understand it could be related to Windows-style (CRLF) line separators. The file must end with a single LF.
https://serverfault.com/questions/854208/ssh-suddenly-returning-invalid-format

I have changed the file to Unix style (using notepad++). Now when I run my playbook it works  till the reset connection task,

```
- name: Restart session (simulate log out and log in)
  ansible.builtin.meta: reset_connection
```

After performing the above task again the "invalid format error" starts showing up and I am not able to proceed.
Internally how the ansible-vault encrypted ssh file is working? Why after reset connection task the ssh key file format is becoming invalid?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"How does SSH key work when encrypted with Ansible vault?"***

A: You can't encrypt *ansible_ssh_private_key_file* by [Ansible vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/index.html). This option is used directly by SSH. SSH is not able to decrypt the Ansible vault. See

```yaml
shell> ansible-doc -t connection ansible.builtin.ssh
  ...
- private_key_file
        Path to private key file to use for authentication.
        set_via:
          cli:
          - name: private_key_file
            option: --private-key
          env:
          - name: ANSIBLE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
          ini:
          - key: private_key_file
            section: defaults
          vars:
          - name: ansible_private_key_file
          - name: ansible_ssh_private_key_file
        default: null
```

The [SSH connection plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py) uses this option to create options for SSH. See

```bash
shell> man ssh
  ...
     -o option
             Can be used to give options in the format used in the configuration file.
             This is useful for specifying options for which there is no separate com‐
             mand-line flag.  For full details of the options listed below, and their
             possible values, see ssh_config(5).

                   AddKeysToAgent
                   AddressFamily
                   BatchMode
                   ...
                   IdentityFile
                   ...
```

See the below [snippet](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py#L768) from the source code

```py
key = self.get_option('private_key_file')
        if key:
            b_args = (b"-o", b'IdentityFile="' + to_bytes(os.path.expanduser(key), errors='surrogate_or_strict') + b'"')
            self._add_args(b_command, b_args, u"ANSIBLE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE/private_key_file/ansible_ssh_private_key_file set")
```

The option *private_key_file* is expanded by the Python method [os.path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) and concatenated to the string "IdentityFile=". You can see that there is no decryption involved.

Notes:

- [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) provides you with the option to encrypt the private key with a [passphrase](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1). See [ssh-keygen: What is the passphrase for?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183636/ssh-keygen-what-is-the-passphrase-for).
- Neither [SSH](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html) (and as a consequence) nor [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html) provide you with the option of submitting the passphrase as an option or on the command line.
- See [SSH agents](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#SSH_agents) on how to provide SSH passphrase.